# What are the available tools we have to customize the UI design for sharepoint online modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page, branding, modern-experience

Since i start working on SharePoint on-premises 2013 & 2016 & online, usually some of our customers want to have their intranet UI to look totally different from sharepoint default UI. so they provide us with a master page + cusotm CSS. and i apply it to all the site collections.

but lately with the advance of modern experience in sharepoint online. seems modern experiences will ignore any custom master pages and custom CSS, so I am not sure how we can apply our customers' custom master pages and CSS files? in other words, if they want to have a custom master pages and custom CSS, then they need to stay working on the classic experience? and they can not combine working on the modern experience and having custom master pages and custom CSS ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a modern theme http://blog.pixelmill.com/3348/changing-colors-modern-site/
2. Use a modern script editor https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor
3. Create custom webparts in react/angular etc like these ones https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples

Comment: thanks for the reply. now i am already using options 2 & 3 , but not sure how they can actually help us in applying custom master pages and cusotm css to our site collections ? second question, now i am working on classic team sites which have modern experience enabled,, so can i still use modern themes (option 1)? or my site collection need to be a modern team site or modern communication site from the beginning and not a classic team site which have modern experience enabled ?

Comment: for modern pages there is no master pages, regardless of point 2 and 3. Microsoft introduced modern pages to prevent users from messing up the master page. Not sure if customer pressure will induce them to replicate what they have removed in the first place. Modern experience (new experience) does not necessarily mean Modern pages. If in your classic site you add modern pages and stick to modern pages for all your pages then it is better that you use my point 1 and create your custom theme (if the Microsoft ones are not your taste).

Comment: New/classic experience is not related to Modern pages, You can have the New experience and Wiki pages or Classic experience and Modern pages.

Comment: yes i am using classic team site which have modern experience, mainly modern pages (inside the sitepages library) and modern list views (for the document libraries and custom lists). so can i create a modern theme in this case?

Comment: yes, follow the tutorial in the page at point one and also use the following pages to understand where your colours go https://laurakokkarinen.com/how-to-create-a-multicolored-theme-for-a-modern-sharepoint-online-site/     the modern theme will not 'override' or 'overlap' the classic one, they will stay separate, so in case you use some old style pages, those will obey to the classic theme 'theming'

Comment: thanks gain, so if i understand your replies well, then i can say, that if we are using modern experience (mainly modern site pages and modern list views), then we can not customize the layout, for example we can not move the search box to be on the left hand side of the page instead of being on the right hand side, or to move the site logo to be on the top of the page, etc (where i use to do these modifications in the on-premises sites be modifying the master page Seattle.html). So in modern experience what we can apply is a theme mainly color and fonts, but nothing deeper than this?

Comment: yes and btw I did not find documentation about changing the default font. This page does not talk about fonts https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-overview    .... Per this article https://laurakokkarinen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-site-designs-and-site-scripts/ .... the future might not be 'master pages' but 'site designs' which btw as they are they do not do things like moving the search box or the logo placeholder. Maybe in the future they will, but not now.

Comment: yes you are correct, i though we will be able to change the fonts beside changing the colors.. so seems in modern experience what we can custom is ONLY the colors by applying modern themes..